# List of files instead of a rendered page when using electron-vue (vue.js with electron)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

i am very new to vue.js and electron. I am trying to render a page with some javascript. 
So i have these .vue files or components. these can contain only one script tag as far as i know. So whenever i add anything to the script. the application breaks and shows me a directory which shows me files

this is how the application apears if i don't modify the script in dashboard.vue

[image: Dashboard.vue]

this is how it apears if i change anything in the script of dashboard.vue

[image]

The dashboard does not contain any script for now. But when i add a script tag this problem occurs.

my dashboard script is

```
<script>
export default {
  name : 'Dashboard',
  data(){
    return  {
      msg : "Welcome"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is how the router is configured . It works fine if i don't have a script tag in dashboard.vue

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      component: require('@/components/Dashboard').default
    },
    {
      path: '/Products',
      name: 'Products',
      component: require('@/components/Products').default
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/'
    }
  ]
})
```

I want to know why this error occurs. and i need to run some script when dashboard is loaded from vue router. I have tried looking up this issue. i can't find anything. I am not that familiar with webpack and vue-loader either. Though i have went through the documentation.

Comment: I have same problem :)

Comment: The culprit was eslint in my case, it gave an error in the logs, something to do with quotes, starting a new project without it fixed the issue

Comment: @Oush Thats great news :)